# Javascript code using SQL statements doesn't work when NVARCHAR has a line break

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ssms

I'm using a PHP app generator (Scriptcase if it matters), and I'm creating a webpage that uses a combination of vanilla JS and SQL queries.

I had an issue and finally I know the reason.

I have a form where you have a big field of type NVARCHAR(max), and in this field you can write text, and when I use return (I go on the next line) then what happens is, my JS code breaks.

If I remove all the new lines then it works.

As you can see from the Chrome debugger, after the line break, the code changes color so it means it s not a string anymore:

[image]

you see in the picture that the string stops being Red, so I think it gets treated as code.

How can I solve this?

This is the JS code:

```
foreach({rsg} as $key=>$step) {
    $var_nodes_array .= 
    '{
                "id": "step_'.$step[0].'",
                "title": "'.$step[1].'",
                "class": "bgwhite,test_'.$step[0].',boards",
                "item": [
    ';

    // Deals
    $sql_deals = " 
    SELECT
        ItemID, 
        ItemName, 
        ItemDescr
    FROM TblItem"

    sc_lookup(rsd, $sql_deals);

    foreach({rsd} as $key=>$val) {  

        // Building the nodes
        $var_nodes_array .= '
                    {
                        "id": "'.$val[0].'",
                        "title": "'.$val[1].'",
                        "class":"color2",
                        "drop": function(el){
                            save(el.dataset.eid, "updstep", $(this).closest("div[data-id]").attr("data-id"));
                        },
                        "items": [
                        {
                            "title":    "'.$val[2].'",
                            "type":     "textEdit",
                            "id":       "tit_'.$val[0].'",
                            "class":    "titleKanban"
                        }
                    ]
                    },';
    }
```

Here the error part is at the end, in the array called Items[], there is "title" field which takes the database value from ItemDescription (which is the NVARCHAR(max) I talked about).

So I need a way to avoid this, if in that Database field there are new lines, to not consider them here somehow, any clue how?

Thank you

EDIT: a little update, if in my form, in the description field, instead of breaking the line with ENTER, I put , and I dont press Enter ever, then the text will be displayed correctly, with line breaks and it won't break the JS, but this is not a good solution, I Can't every time that I need a line break, put that tag! So basically when I use ENTER and submit the field, it gets sent to the DB with those line breaks, and when the JS code retrieves the value of that field, it gets messed up because of the line breaks

EDIT2: I tried using `$val_test = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $val[1]);`

as suggested by an answer, but the output is that the JS is still broken, but now it adds \n on each new line as you can see in the picture

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can escape the newlines for Javascript by using something like

```
str_replace("\n", "\\n", $val);
```

If you also have `\r` characters in the text they need to be removed, so use this instead:

```
str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), array("\\n", ""), $val);
```

This will turn

```
line 1

line 2
```

into

```
line 1\n\nline 2
```

which you can then assign to a JS variable e.g.

```js
let x = "line 1\n\nline 2";
console.log(x);
```

Comment: I tried this, I used your trick by assigning the val[1] which is the description to a new var so I can use that method :

$val_region = str_replace("\n", "\\n", $val[1]);

but this is the output, still broken, but you can see that for every new line now it adds \n  

I dont know how to add images to a comment, gonna edit my OP with the new image

Comment: @AJ989 you probably have `\r` characters in there as well. Can you try `str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), array("\\n", ""), $val);`

Comment: you are my saviour, this works PERFECTLY, I was going crazy, thank you so much!!!

Comment: @AJ989 good to hear. I'll update my answer so it helps anyone else that sees it.

Comment: hey could you help me out with an addition? I'm having the same issue if we use double quotes:  "  . So can you help me and add to the str_replace you gave me, something to make it when it finds a double quote, it transforms it in 2x single quotes?

Comment: I solved this by just creating a new var, and passing the previous Var that has the str_replace for the line break, and do another str_replace like this

$val_desc1 = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), array("\\n", ""), $val[2]);
  $val_desc = str_replace('"', "'", $val_desc1);

and it works!

Comment: @AJ989 sorry about lack of response, it's been night here. Glad you got it sorted, you could simplify by adding extra elements to each of the arrays in the call to `str_replace` e.g. `str_replace(array("\n", "\r", '"'), array("\\n", "", "'"), $val);`